# Passing Custom headers (sessionid) in fresco

Tags: android, okhttp, fresco

I want to pass the sessionid as the header while downloading the image in fresco.
I tried this code

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor{chain ->
          chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("YourHeader", "value").build());
    }.build();

Fresco.initialize(mContext, OkHttpImagePipelineConfigFactory.newBuilder(mContext, okHttpClient).build());
```

but this doesn't help as I will not have the session while initializing the fresco

Comment: `Interceptor` will only get called when a request is made.  So whenever you are getting the Session Id save it in Some storage maybe in `SharedPreferences` and then get it inside `Interceptor` and set it as header .